# Add icon to a cx_Freeze script

Tags: python, icons, cx-freeze

How to add an icon to an executable made with cx_Freeze?
I was looking for a solution on google & stackoverflow, but I couldn't find any.

This is my `setup.py`

```py
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"includes": ["tkinter"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for
# a console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "YouTube-Video-Downloader",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("app.py", base=base)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an icon to your executable using the `icon` argument of the `Executable`:

```py
setup(  name = "YouTube-Video-Downloader",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("app.py", base=base, icon="path_to_icon_file")])
```

The given icon file needs to be a valid icon file for Windows. See also the [cx_Freeze documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#cx-freeze-executable).